# Find function that satisfy the relation

Tags: asymptotics

Can you find the function that satisfy the relation?

$$f(n) = \Theta(g(n)), f(n) = o(g(n))$$

Comment: Can you update the question adding some hints on what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Check the definitions (as commonly used in Computer Science, mostly for run time or other resource consumption):

$f(n) = O(g(n))$ if there is a constant $c_1 > 0$ so that for some $N_1$ we have for $n \ge N_1$ that $f(n) \le c_1 g(n)$

$f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ if there is a constant $c_2 > 0$ so that for some $N_2$ we have for $n \ge N_2$ that $f(n) \ge c_2 g(n)$

$f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ if both $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$

$f(n) = o(g(n))$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$

$f(n) \sim g(n)$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1$

$f(n) = \omega(g(n))$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \infty$

You see that $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ (one part of $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$) and $f(n) = o(g(n))$ can't be true simultaneously (check the definition of the limit).

Answer (score 0):

If `oh` is little, it is not possible. Because of the definition of these two symbols. $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ means there is two constants $c_1, c_2 > 0$ and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g(n) < c_1 f(n)$ and $f(n) < c_2 g(n)$ for $n > n_0$. Hence, it means $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = constant > 0 $.

However, the definition of the `little-oh` is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$ and there is not constant $c$ and $n_1$, such that $g(n) < c f(n)$ for $n > n_1$.

Also, if you mean `big-oh`, by the definition, you can say if $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$, you can always say $f(n) = O(g(n))$ too.

Comment: There is something strange with your definition of $\Theta$: e.g. if $f=1$ and $g=(1/2)^{(-1)^n}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} f/g$ does not exists, although you can find constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ as you describe above.

Comment: The essence of your comments remains valid anyway.

Comment: @Leo163 you're right. But as a matter of complexity, I assume that $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are functions in natural numbers and positive.

Comment: Even with these assumptions there is a problem: just take $f$ as above and let $g'$ be $2g$: they are both function with $\mathbb{Z}^+$ as range, but the issue of nonexistence of the limit exists.